# Where to upload files in Jboss and later download them?

Tags: tomcat, file-upload, download, jboss7.x, catalina

We are moving one web app from Tomcat 7.0 to Jboss 7.1. In this web app there is a possibility to upload documents by the users. These documents can be then downloaded or deleted by the users as well.

The documents have been stored within the web application (**this is a requirement**, so we cannot store the documents in a DB or in another folder outside of the app on the web container).

When using Tomcat I could have done smth. like the following in java code to get an existing absolute path to the directory where the files were stored:

```
    String catalinaHome = "";
    String dataPath = "";

    try {
        if (System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME") != null) {
            catalinaHome = System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME");
        } else if (System.getProperty("catalina.base") != null) {
            catalinaHome = System.getProperty("catalina.base");
        }

        dataPath = catalinaHome + "/webappsdata/" + APP_NAME + UPLOADED_FILES;
```

**How can I achieve the same or similar goal when we I now use Jboss 7.1 instead of Tomcat?**

Using smth. like System.getProperty("JBOSS_HOME") didn't work for me.

Thanx a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following solution, which might not be elegant, but works for me. Using **System.getProperties()** I have got a loads of properties. The one keys that were interesting for me were: **"jboss.server.data.dir"** and **"${project.artifactId}${project.version}"** (the 2nd one gives you an absolute path to the deployed app).

Hope it helps somebody.